# Menu button can not be clicked on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've used Ruby menu in my website from [this example](https://codepen.io/tisonmuhammad/pen/qrjEbK):

It works fine on desktop.

But it is not working on mobile devices (Button can not be clicked). 
The console shows an error that it is failed to load 3 js files:

http://brienlabs.com/ruby-mega-menu/js/ruby-main.js

http://brienlabs.com/ruby-mega-menu/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js

http://brienlabs.com/ruby-mega-menu/js/ruby-demo.js

I tried to add those 3 files on my site but it is still not working and shows me below errors.

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://brienlabs.com/ruby-mega-menu/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js”. index.html:2779:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://brienlabs.com/ruby-mega-menu/js/ruby-demo.js”. index.html:2779:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://brienlabs.com/ruby-mega-menu/js/ruby-main.js”.
```

Please, can anyone assist me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this “, but it'll be ". Those are different from each other. Please check it. I hope it'll work.

Wrong

```
“https://brienlabs.com/ruby-mega-menu/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js”
```

Correct
    "https://brienlabs.com/ruby-mega-menu/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"

Comment: I don't see your JS/jQuery Code. Where is it? If you don't have it, you should write code about addClass/removeClass etc.. what you need.

Comment: In JS section..Go to the settings icon. There you can find those three js

Comment: I don't say about three (CDN) js. You could write JS/jQuery code for add/delete dynamic. You don't write that code. If you never write, this will not work.
You should investigate this example =   https://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/MKXweV



Especially if you examine the JavaScript section, I believe it will solve the problem.